# A Straightforward Connect Wall

Tags: pattern, connect-wall

Place the words below into 4 groups, each containing 4 words which share a common property.

The answer to this puzzle is a description of the 4 groups along with the list of words that belong in each.

(Inspired by [Connecting Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_Connect#Round_3:_Connecting_Wall) a.k.a. [NYT Connections](https://www.nytimes.com/games/connections) puzzles.)

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHURCH | HILL | TONIC | LAND |
| WARD | GHOST | ROOT | TIME |
| GLASS | BASE | ONE | NOSE |
| HEART | BOOK | TOWN | CONTRACT |

Comment: rot13(fcvevg tynff gbavp ebbg (orre)?)

Comment: @RonchenLuo Nope

Comment: ynaq, jneq, uvyy, ebbg (hc?)

Comment: @LizardofOz Nope, but this line of thinking is not entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the groups are as follows (some of these groups were also identified by PDT):

Group 1

> Words which can follow **HOLY** to yield a well-known phrase - CHURCH, [LAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Land), [GHOST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Spirit_in_Christianity), [BOOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_text)

Group 2

> Words to which **DOWN** can be added to the beginning to give another word - HILL, WARD, TIME, TOWN

Group 3

> Words which can follow **BROKEN** to yield a well-known phrase - CONTRACT, GLASS, NOSE, HEART

Group 4

> Words which are associated as being the "initial note" in some way - [TONIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonic_(music)) (first note in a scale), [ROOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_(chord)) (first  note in a chord), [BASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_(perfumery)) (bottom note in perfumery), ONE (first note in a bar of music)

Comment: @PDT Yes, I can. I think there is a rep boundary where you can see deleted answers (maybe 10,000?). I also saw your answer originally when you posted it.

Comment: can confirm 10k is the boundary having just passed it recently

Comment: @hb20007 Okay, there is another theory I was working on which doesn't involve sub but I couldn't quite formulate it. Will try to edit my answer with this in mind.